# Linear time sorting of integers of size 2^n

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

### Problem

I need to design an algorithm that takes a list of integers as an input and returns a sorted list of the elements greater than the first `log(n)` and smaller than the last `n - 3 log(n)` (in other words, I need a sorted list of `2log(n)` elements). The integers of the array are between 0 and 2^n. They must be sorted in linear time `O(n)`, where n is the number of elements in the entire list. The fact that we only need a subset of the elements sorted might be relevant to finding a solution but I haven't found its relationship.

### My solutions

I have tried two solutions.

1. Using counting sort, but that yields and exponential (`2^n`) time and space complexity
2. Using radix sort, but that yields a quadratic time complexity. This is due to the fact that
   `T(n) = O(d*(n + b)) = O(log_b(2^n)*(n + b)) = O(n * log_b(2) * (n + b)) = O(n^2)` independently of the value of b.

As you can see I am a little lost into what to try next. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it means O(n) time complexity

Comment: Please add to the question a) what exactly *n* is (count of input numbers as a measure of problem size?) b) what machine model to use - with [RAM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine), you'd have to "fix" a register size, conventionally in O(log n).

Comment: a) I added the n as the number of elements in the array b) mmm I don't understand what you mean with a type of machine... you should presume that it is a theorical problem. I don't think the machine has a relationship with the solution.

Comment: @greybeard Mmm, are you saying that given that there is a fixed register size 2^n has an upper bound? Thus making it a constant?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the problem. The 4* log(n) could be independent on the solution but I wanted you to have all the information I have. In fact, I think they same way as you do. That is why I calculated the complexities using the whole array of size n and not n - 4logn

Comment: I get you hahaha either way is there a solution to "sort a list where the range of elements is GIGANTIC in linear time"?

Comment: Conventional wisdom has it that there's no way to sort by key comparison (each taking constant time) an unsorted collection of *n* items in less than O(*n*log*n*) time. While GIGANTIC range discourages going "the counting sort route", neither it nor ignoring an negligible amount of items helping any.

Comment: n-logn-(n-3logn)=2logn, not n-4logn

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername the numbers should be smaller than the last n - 3logn. So there are 3 logn numbers bigger + 1logn smaller

Comment: @polmonroig In total you have `n` numbers. Out of them you subtract the first `logn` numbers and the last `n-3logn` numbers ==> You are left with `n-logn-(n-3logn)=2logn` numbers. At least that's what you wrote.

Comment: Okay, sorry. You are right. As N grows the output list becomes smaller. But to get that sorted list we must sort all of them, right?

Comment: @גלעדברקן if there is a way to get the smaller unsorted list of sizd 2logn. We can sort it using radix sort in lognlogn time

Comment: @polmonroig `we must sort all of them, right?` Wrong, fortunately: first *[select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)* then *sort*.

Comment: There still is that issue of machine (in)capabilities: A RAM could not represent a number with a range of 2ⁿ in a single word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit goes to SomeWittyUsername for correcting the original question requirements.

"Greater than the first log(n) and smaller than the last n - 3 log(n) elements."

Find the `log(n)`th number and the `(n - 3*log(n))`th number by quickselect in `O(n)`.

Filter the list to remove `log(n) + n - 3*log(n) = n - 2*log(n)` items.

We now have `n - (n - 2*log(n)) = 2*log(n)` items with range `2^n`.

Sorting `O(log(n))` elements by comparison sorting takes `O(log(n) * log(log(n))) << O(n)` time.

Comment: I think that's perfect.